# Effective update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `Value_table` and column `value`
I need to update `value` column as 'Hi' if any `value` column exists with 'bye'
I wrote query

```
UPDATE Value_table
SET value = 'Hi'
WHERE value_id
IN
(
    SELECT
        value_id
    FROM 
        Value_table 
    WHERE 
        value = 'bye'
)
```

It works fine.Now since I'm using the same table in sub query can we make any other way to make this statement in more efficient.?

Comment: Is value_id a unique key for the table? Or can you provide sample data?

Comment: Why does using the same table in a subquery make a difference?

Comment: @domnic: You asked over 80 questions and yet walk away the second after you ask a question. Please stay put to answer comments in the first, most important minutes of a question.

Answer (score 2):

If `value_id` is unique you can do

```
UPDATE Value_table
SET value = 'Hi'
WHERE value = 'bye'
```

Comment: i didnt downvote, but probably because of `if any value column exists with 'bye'`

Comment: No this can produce different result.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I think it was when first posted, this answer didn't include the text "If `valud_id` is unique" which is a critical piece of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

i guess if the table is really large, EXISTS might perform better.

```
UPDATE  vt
SET     vt.value = 'Hi'
FROM    Value_table vt
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT  1 
                FROM    Value_table vt2 
                WHERE   vt.value_id = vt2.value_id AND vt2.value = 'bye')
```

`if any value column exists with 'bye'`  if that means the id does not have to match, you can remove the `vt.value_id = vt2.value_id` portion